# Xpath web scraping

Tags: xpath

I am wanting to get some information from a website with xpath, the problem is that results from 1 to 2000
I was wondering how to use a few xpath lines to get all the content, example:

```
// * [@ id = "block-table"] / tbody / tr [1] / td [1]
// * [@ id = "block-table"] / tbody / tr [2] / td [1]
// * [@ id = "block-table"] / tbody / tr [3] / td [1]
// * [@ id = "block-table"] / tbody / tr [4] / td [1]
```

In case only changes the numbers, has a way to get all the content with just a few lines? No need to put 1, 2, 3, 4 ... in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
'//*[@id="block-table"]/tbody/tr[position() <= 2000]/td[1]'
```

or

```
'(//*[@id="block-table"]/tbody/tr/td[1])[position() <= 2000]'
```

Comment: Thanks man, but it didn't work out. I am using an extension in Chrome called Scraper, gave the following error: [object Object]. I am trying to get the results from the site https://ipinfo.io/AS4837

Comment: Removed typo from xpath. Tested on the site, I get the required `td` array